# How does one use SFTP noninteractively to download a file from a remote host?

Tags: password, scp, sftp, key-authentication

I have a laptop and a raspberry pi acting as a storage server. I'd like to know how to download a file without any user interaction other than running the program. I read through the man page, and there doesn't seem to be a way to specify a password on the `scp` or `sftp` command line.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` and its cousin `sftp`, because they are written to be secure (it's right there in the name after all) by design to not allow for passwords to be provided on the commandline, as that's a very easy way to leak your passwords into a plaintext log file such as the shell's history.

If you want to enable headless, yet still authenticated, file transfer, create a public/private keypair with `ssh-keygen` but provide a blank passphrase.  You can then use that keypair to authenticate for your `sftp` transaction once the public key has been installed on the remote host.

If you *really* want to use `sftp` you will also have to send the commands *to* `sftp` that you'd ordinarily enter on its interactive prompt.  It would be simpler to use `scp`:

```
$ scp username@remotehost.example.com /path/to/my/file ./file
```

Comment: scp has been deprecated. An [LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/835962/) discusses why, and what can be done.

Comment: That article is discussing a _proposal_ for deprecating `scp`; I have not seen that it actually has been.  Indeed, that article is discussing at its conclusion an in-place stand-in for `scp` that will still DTRT with current invocations while acting as a shim for `sftp`.